# XSL get iteration in a condition in a foreach

Tags: xslt, foreach, position, conditional-statements

I would like get iteration number in XSL, but in my foreach i have a condition and i woulde like write my iteration, but only for true in my condition.

I use "position()" and i would like write position in a table.

```
<xsl:for-each ... >
  <xsl:if test="Jordan = $name">
    <xsl:value-of select="position() = 1">
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

After i get this 1-3, I would like 1-2 (only success condition)

MY XML :

```
<root>
  <user>
    <name>Jordan</name>
    <forename>Michael</forename>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>Braun</name>
    <forename>Steve</forename>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>Jordan</name>
    <forename>David</forename>
  </user>
</root>
```

the expected output a HTML table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Michael</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>David</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would help to see the XML you're working on, as well as the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: The OP has altered their question to provide new information. This requires an answer different than the original one.**

If the goal is to output info only for those `<user>` elements whose `<name>` child is "Jordan", this XSLT should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name = 'Jordan']/forename"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="forename">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**EDIT: This answer is left for posterity.**

Rather than looking at this as an "incrementing loop problem" (which is more of a procedural methodology), I would look at this problem -- at least, as it pertains to XSLT -- as a grouping problem. Doing this in XSLT 1.0 means using [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kForenames" match="forename" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="*/forename[generate-id() =
                           generate-id(key('kForenames', .)[1])]"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="forename">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the provided XML:**

```
<root>
  <user>
    <name>Jordan</name>
    <forename>Michael</forename>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>Braun</name>
    <forename>David</forename>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>Jordan</name>
    <forename>David</forename>
  </user>
</root>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Michael</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>David</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is the test="Jordan = $name" ?

Comment: @WhitneyR. - based on your expected output, that condition doesn't appear to be required. Again, using a grouping methodology ensures that no duplicate forenames appear.

Comment: I would like select user with name "jordan" !

Comment: Your edit alters the nature of your question. Please see my update and let me know if that does what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="mergedData">
     <xsl:for-each ... >
          <xsl:if test="Jordan = $name">
               <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($mergedData)/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```